# How to simplify nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am trying to draw a square with label, but i think nodes can be simplify.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- cycle;
\draw (2,0) -- (4,2) -- (2,4) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
\node[below left] at (0,0) {A};
\node[above left] at (0,4) {B};
\node[above right] at (4,4) {C};
\node[below right] at (4,0) {D};
\node[above] at (1,4) {b};
\node[above] at (3,4) {c};
\node[right] at (4,3) {b};
\node[right] at (4,1) {c};
\node[below] at (3,0) {b};
\node[below] at (1,0) {c};
\node[left] at (0,1) {b};
\node[left] at (0,3) {c};
\node[left] at (1,1) {a};
\node[left] at (1,3) {a};
\node[right] at (3,1) {a};
\node[right] at (3,3) {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE. In which sense you like to simplify your nodes. they can not be more simple ... probably you mean how to place it at lines. see, if `tikzlibrary` `quotes` can help you in this.

Comment: I mean these nodes can be written by \node[left] at (1,1)(1,3) {a}; or anything to cut down the nodes. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: you can use a `\path` macro, which lets you declare multiple nodes at once. It won't save you that many keystrokes though.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you probably look something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (0,0) node[below left]  {A} to ["b"] (0,2) to ["c"] 
        (0,4) node[above left]  {B} to ["b"] (2,4) to ["c"]
        (4,4) node[above right] {C} to ["b"] (4,2) to ["c"]
        (4,0) node[below right] {D} to ["b"] (2,0) to ["c"]  cycle;
\draw   (2,0) to ["$a$" '] 
        (4,2) to ["$a$" '] 
        (2,4) to ["$a$" '] 
        (0,2) to ["$a$" '] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives the same result as your code:

[image]